# Thymeleaf and DatePicker: set min Date

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, thymeleaf

I would like to set a minimum selectable date in my datepicker, using  thymeleaf.

I try to set it by this code:

```
<label th:utext="#{${name}}" th:for="${name}" class="control-label"></label>
<div class="input-group input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text far fa-calendar-alt"></span>
   <input type="text" th:id="${name}" th:name="${name}" th:value="${value}" th:placeholder="${placeholder}" class="form-control" onfocus="(this.type='date')" min="${minDate}"/>
</div>
```

But this code `min="${minDate}"` is ignored.

There is a way to do that I want with `thymeleaf` or I can do it only by `javascript`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `th:attr` as below

```
th:attr="min=${minDate}"
```